# Como fazer um Split para quando houver uma letra na string?

Tags: c#, .net, string

Eu gostaria de fazer uma *string* ser dividida com o `.Split()` toda vez que houvesse uma letra. Exemplo:

A *string*: `97A96D112A109X115T114H122D118Y128`

Viraria um *array* com 9 valores: `{ 97 96 112 109 115 114 122 118 128 }`

Como eu posso fazer isso?

Código que tenho (para usar como base):

```
string[] az = txt.Split(/*Parametros aqui*/);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use o [`Split()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_String_Split_System_Char___) para quebrar usando um *array* com todos os caracteres que podem ser quebras. Para facilitar, ainda que não seja o mais performático (mas nada exagerado) pode criar uma *string* e transformar em um *array* de `char` com [`ToCharArray()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_String_ToCharArray). Dá para fazer em uma linha. Se quiser o máximo de performance crie o *array* na mão.

Se precisar das minúsculas também é só incluí-las. Verifique na documentação as opções se precisar de modos específicos de quebra.

```
using static System.Console;
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var partes = "97A96D112A109X115T114H122D118Y128".Split("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZ".ToCharArray());
        foreach (var item in partes) WriteLine(item); //só para confirmar que deu certo
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/BCqpIY). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e4aSCY). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/SplitOnChar.cs).

Comment: Por que não usar expressão regular?

Comment: @TiagoA https://xkcd.com/1171/ RegEx é uma das coisas mais feias e esquisitas que já criam, escondendo problemas de performance. Pra que usar algo complexo quando o simples resolve? Acho engraçado quase todo mundo falar de legibilidade de código e depois usar RegEx.

Comment: Performance depende da linguagem: https://github.com/mariomka/regex-benchmark. Simples pra mim é trocar o alfabeto inteiro por `[a-zA-Z]+`.

Comment: @TiagoA Varia de linguagem para linguagem, mas não depende da linguagem. É fisicamente impossível uma expressão de A + B ser mais lenta que um cálculo complexo que quase todas operações matemáticas possíveis. RegEx é um mecanismo extremamente sofisticado, é uma linguagem dentro da linguagem, ele tem que fazer coisas que a maioria dos programadores sequer sonham ser possíveis, ele gerará um código complexo para executar aquilo. E isso se estiver falando de otimizações que algumas linguagens fazem, se ele tiver que compilar a expressão antes de usar aí a tragédia toma proporções absurdas.

Comment: Até quem defende o seu uso sabe que é trágico e você só deve usar se não liga pra performance, o que em alguns casos pode não ligar mesmo, mas em muitos é a diferença entre a aplicação ser aceitável ou não. Eu já ouvi falar que em casos extremamente complexos fazer na mão dá tanto trabalho, pode haver confusão e até ficar mais lento que o RegEx, mas na prática nunca ninguém demonstrou isso claramente e o ainda teria que contar com um erro do programador.

Comment: Vou dizer mais, esse teste é muito furado, C# tem um RegEx muito bom, não tem como ele estar nas últimas posições, já não confio em resultado algum demonstrado ali. A pessoa que fez o teste não sabe usar direito. Uma pena você achar minha resposta ruim, porque fazer da melhor forma. Algumas pessoas querem aprender certo outras não. Nem o critério usado está correto. Você mostrou um teste que não compara um `Split()`simples contra um RegEx, faça você um teste com os dois, se o RegEx for for mais rápido eu apago a resposta. O que você faz, além de tirar o negativo se o Split()` for mais rápido?

Comment: RegEx é uma ferramenta incrível e que já salvou minha vida. Por exemplo find/replace na IDE. Porém é algo muito pontual e como qualquer ferramenta, o seu uso deve ser feito com responsabilidade, tanto pela performance, quanto pela legibilidade quanto pela previsibilidade. Você pode escrever uma expressão que aparentemente funciona maravilhosamente, testá-la e achar que está tudo ok - até o dia em que perceber que ela faz sentido em outro contexto e dá match em algo que não deveria.

Comment: Uma série de vulnerabilidades em frameworks PHP (ex recente: ThinkPHP) aconteceram porque alguém resolveu usar RegEx pra validar algo, neste caso do ThinkPHP um mecanismo de IoC/Reflexão (era algo assim) no nome da classe, e lógico que alguém conseguiu quebrar a expressão e apartir dali executou código arbitrário. :D

Comment: RegEx é análogo ao martelinho vermelho com botão do mecanismo anti-incêndio: Ele existe, há um bom motivo para que ele exista, e há casos em que ele é necessário e previne algo pior que o desconforto que possa ser causado pelo seu uso (ex: todo mundo ficar encharcado X todo mundo morrer carbonizado), mas não é o tipo de ferramenta que você vai usar pra tudo, porque nesse caso implica mais riscos do que seria razoável ter de aceitar.

Comment: https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/fastest/csharp.html esse é mais confiável porque é feito porque quem entende da linguagem. Note que é próximo do C++ https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/fastest/csharpcore-gpp.html. È claro que se você falar em outras linguagens a coisa muda de figura. Por exemplo Java, o `Split()` usa um RegEx internamente, então sempre o `Split()` será igual ou pior que o RegEx puro (ainda que você terá que fazer mais operações no puro então ainda pode ser um pouco mais lento. Em Java é melhor fazer na mão de tão ruim que é.

Answer (score 7):

Tente assim:

```
string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
string[] az = txt.Split(alphabet.ToCharArray());
```

Answer (score 6):

Você conseguiria fazer isso utilizando o [char.IsLetter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.char.isletter(v=vs.110).aspx). ficaria assim:

```
string az= "97A96D112A109X115T114H122D118Y128";

string[] novaString;

foreach (char c in az)
{
    if(char.IsLetter(c)
    {
        string[] novaString = az.Split(c);
    }
}
```

Ai você acessa assim: `novaString[0] novaString[1]`

Answer (score 6):

Uma outra alternativa é utilizar expressões regulares (`System.Text.RegularExpressions`) através de um padrão na 'linguagem' de busca Regex para fazer os "matches" (correspondências de valores) de apenas números e então usar Linq (`System.Linq`) para pegar o resultado, no caso uma coleção, fazer o 'cast' para um `IEnumerable` do tipo `Match`, desse `IEnumerable` tipado pegarmos somente os valores que queremos na propriedade 'value' e então convertermos para um array de strings, desse array usamos o método `Join` da classe `String` e então usamos o `Split`. Na verdade não há necessidade do `Join` e nem do `Split` e o código fica mais simples ainda. Deixo as duas opções para comparação.

1) Sem `Split`:

```
// varias linhas
string value = "97A96D112A109X1X15T114H122D118Y128";
var matches = Regex.Matches(value, "[0-9]+");
var arrayOfNumbers = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();

// uma linha apenas
string[] arrayOfNumbers = Regex.Matches("97A96D112A109X1X15T114H122D118Y128", "[0-9]+")
.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```

2) Com `Split`:

```
string value = "97A96D112A109X1X15T114H122D118Y128";
var matches = Regex.Matches(value, "[0-9]+");
var arrayOfNumbers = String.Join("-", matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray()).Split('-');
```

Answer (score 5):

Você pode utilizar uma lista com os caracteres necessários para realizar o split do seu array:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SplitTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var text = "97A96D112A109X115T114H122D118Y128";
            var separatorList = new List<char>();

            // ASCII TABLE
            // 0X41 = A
            // 0X5A = Z

            for (int i = 0X41; i < 0X5B; i++)
            {
                separatorList.Add((char)i);
            }

            var result = text.Split(separatorList.ToArray());

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Além do que já foi respondido anteriormente você pode usar expressão regular 'Regex' com a função replace, substituindo os caracteres indesejados, neste caso substituí por um traço '-', depois basta usar o 'Split' com esse caracter '-'.

```
 string txt = "97A96D112A109X115T114H122D118Y128";
 string[] az = Regex.Replace(txt, "[^0-9]", "-").Split('-');
```